Trying to deserialise and the JSON value could not be converted to class(?)
very newbie programmer here trying to learn C#. I'm trying to deserialise a JSON file and then print the values inside. However, I'm met with a Jsonexception in the form of cannot be converted to the class I made.
The code in question:
public class Games
{
    public string? Title { get; set;}
    public int ReleaseYear { get; set;}
    public double Rating { get; set;}
}

public class ReadAndParseJSONFromFile()
{
    public static void ReadingJSON()
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\Users\Kodain\C#\Game Data Parser\games.json";
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        Games games = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Games>(jsonString)!;
        System.Console.WriteLine("Loaded games are: ");
        System.Console.WriteLine($"{games.Title}, released in {games.ReleaseYear}, rating: {games.Rating}");
    }
}

and the provided JSON file:
[
  {
    "Title": "Stardew Valley",
    "ReleaseYear": 2016,
    "Rating": 4.9
  },
  {
    "Title": "Frostpunk",
    "ReleaseYear": 2017,
    "Rating": 4.7
  },
  {
    "Title": "Oxygen Not Included",
    "ReleaseYear": 2017,
    "Rating": 4.8
  },
  {
    "Title": "Red Dead Redemtpion II",
    "ReleaseYear": 2018,
    "Rating": 4.8
  },
  {
    "Title": "Portal 2",
    "ReleaseYear": 2011,
    "Rating": 4.8
  }
]

I tried to use the Microsoft documentation on how to deserialise since I've never done it before with JSON, only text files. I expected the program to read the JSON file, then print out all the games with title, release year, and rating. Instead I got a Jsonexception that tells me that the JSON value cannot be converted to Games:
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.Text.Json.JsonException
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Text.Json.JsonException' occurred in System.Text.Json.dll: 'The JSON value could not be converted to Games.'
I tried my google-fu, but I too much of a noob and cannot seem to find a solution to my problem. I am quite stumped.

You should rename the class into Game and use an array type as the target type for serialization: Game[] games = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Game[]>(jsonString)!;

To expand on @Silvermind's comment, the [ bracket at the start of your JSON specifies that this is a list of data, so when you deserialize to a single object it will fail. Therefore you need to deserialize to a list of your object as recommended above.

The JSON is having a List of games. You should Deserialize to List<Games>
     public static void ReadingJSON()
        {
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\Kodain\C#\Game Data Parser\games.json";
            string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            var games = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Games>>(jsonString)!;
            System.Console.WriteLine("Loaded games are: ");
            foreach(var game in games)
            {
                 System.Console.WriteLine($"{game.Title}, released in 
                  {game.ReleaseYear}, rating: {game.Rating}");
            }
        }

